# Method to raise windows service automatically

Tags: c#, windows-services

Good morning everyone,

I'm new to C # and already have a challenge ahead.  I have never programmed professionally, and I have a dilemma concerning the services of C#.

We have a service and I was wondering if there is any method to do the job automatically.  For example: my service runs 24 hours a day.  Even with the property CanStop set to false, the service can sometimes occur fall, either for lack of energy, the terminal being rebooted, or any other problem.

The only thing I've tried so far is setting a method to restart the service from time to time, but this isn't good for me because it will greatly influence the performance of own work and the windows service.

Could someonegive me a hand?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague but from what I can tell you are asking:

> Is it possible to restart a failed Windows service automatically?

It's possible to do this using the facilities built into Windows. If you open the properties of your service via the Services utility (in Control Panel → Adminstrative Tools) you can control what happens if your service fails on the 'Recovery' tab.

Comment: I was just going to answer that a watchdog is needed when I saw your answer. Curios - what does it mean for the service to fail in the context of these settings?

Comment: +1 And also the more simple setting to Automatically start the Windows service on startup - again within Administrative Tools - Services (if indeed keeping a Windows service up as much as possible is what's being asked)

Comment: @Bond - I am not 100% sure but I would expect it to mean 'exit with a non-zero exit code'. Edit: apparently it doesn't mean that at all. [This resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685939(VS.85).aspx) explains in what situation the recovery kicks in. [This article](http://mdenomy.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/using-the-automatic-recovery-features-of-windows-services/) explains it a bit better.

Comment: @Adriel Felipe. See the link in my comment above, that should explain everything to you. Basically you will need to ensure that your process ends abruptly in case of error, which is the default behaviour for an unhandled exception. (Sshh, don't tell anyone but I'm not American either.)